# Using Jenkins plugin for SonarQube with two different installs and getting unexpected url for the new one

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

Got two SonarQube install behind a Nginx proxy, slowly upgrading.

Old 4.1 one and a new 4.5 LTS one.

For the 4.1 the url returned is the public facing url in the build result.

For the 4.5 the url is the internal url for the build result.

The Jenkins plugin seems to be configured the same so not sure why the new one is giving the internal url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases the Jenkins plugin is using the URL that is printed at the end of analysis logs.
Have you properly defined "sonar.core.serverBaseURL" in SQ Server settings?

Comment: Thanks, found it under "Settings -> General" in the UI on the old server.  Moved it to the settings file to make sure it does not get lost again.